# Javascript object instance and document ready

Tags: javascript, oop, dom

This code gives me an error:

```
$(function(){
    var instance = new object();
    literal.call();
});
var literal ={
    call : function(){
        instance.foo();
    }
}
function object(){
    this.selector = $('div');
    this.foo = function(){ this.selector.remove(); }
}
```

I want to make it run and I want to let the literal object out from $(function(){}). I don't want to change the selector at a later time.

So I discarded this solution

```
$(function(){
    instance.selector = $('div');
    literal.call();
});
var instance = new object();
var literal ={
    call : function(){
        instance.foo();
    }
}
function object(){
    this.selector = $('div');
    this.foo = function(){ this.selector.remove(); }
}
```

And I discarded this also

```
$(function(){
var instance = new object();
var literal ={
    call : function(){
        instance.foo();
    }
}
literal.call();
});
function object(){
    this.selector = $('div');
    this.foo = function(){ this.selector.remove(); }
}
```

what is the best practice to do this?

Comment: creating a function named `object` is a bad idea and will likely lead to major confusion.

Comment: Any code that's dependent on a variable assigned in the document ready should also be in the document ready, so it doesn't run before the variable is assigned. If you could explain the higher level goal, maybe we could help you design it properly -- it's hard to understand from your generic code.

Comment: Thanks barmar. I know it. But is it a good pratice to insert literal objects in the document ready (as I made in the last piece of code)? or it isn't reccomendable?

Comment: I don't think there's a general answer to this. Depending on the situation, different approaches may be preferable. You could even pass `instance` as an argument to `call()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `istance` variable was local to the ready handler. As you don't want to move your code in there (for whatever reasons), you will need to make the variable global:

```
var istance;
$(function(){
    istance = new object();
    literal.call();
});
var literal = {
    call: function() {
        istance.foo();
    }
}
function object(){
    this.selector = $('div');
    this.foo = function(){ this.selector.remove(); }
}
```